# Keep getting error in R when trying to deploy app to shinyapps.io: Error in func(fname, ...) : app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object

Tags: r, shiny

I am very new to both R and am creating a shiny app for the first time. My app works fine locally but I can't get it to deploy to shinyapps.io correctly. The app should be a line graph of numeric survey responses over time. The user of the chart should be able to select the demographic they want to view the survey responses for.

Could someone please tell me where my code is incorrect:

```
library(shiny)
library(rsconnect)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='xxx',
                          token='xxx',
                          secret='xxx')

data_mod <- read.csv("dataex2", header=TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Trends over time"),
  sidebarLayout(position = "right",
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("demographics", 
                  label = "Choose a Demographic to display",
                  choices = unique(data_mod$demographics)),
      mainPanel()),
      plotOutput("line")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$line <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data_mod %>% filter(demographics == input$demographics), 
           aes(Year, value, color = Column, group = Column)) + geom_line()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I then press publish in the shiny app that is created.

Some example code to get a dataframe could be:

```
Column <- c("Very important", "Unsure", "Not important", "Very important", "Unsure", "Not important", "Very important", "Unsure", "Not important", "Very important", "Unsure", "Not important")
Year <- c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016)
demographics <- c(total, total, total, female, female, female, total, total, total, female, female, female)
value <- c(0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 0.7, 0.1, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4)

df <- data.frame(Column, Year, demographics, value)
```

I tried to run this code and deploy the app to shinyapps.io. It didn't work. I have tried several iterations to try and get it to work and am really confused about why it's not working. I have been using a Mac.

I have looked at other posts on this forum and on other similar forums for answers and have also read up on common errors.

Comment: Not sure if this is what's preventing the deployment or not, but `rsconnect::setAccountInfo()` shouldn't be in the app code - you run that once anywhere and then Rstudio knows where to deploy.